# haveing trouble with php form (posting error)

Tags: php

Im fairly new to PHP and having some trouble with it posting the validation data (Form)

error that keeps poping up
(sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. these errors appear below.
The name you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Email you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Phone Number you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Chairpersons name you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Chairpersons Email you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Number of trustees you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Number of students you entered does not appear to be valid.
please go back and fix these errors.)

if you want to have a look for youself http://wwsta.org.nz/Membership%20Application%20Full%20Board.html

PHP code...

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "me@myemail.com";
$email_subject = "Membership Application";
}

function died($error) {
    echo " sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. " ;
    echo "these errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error. "<br /><br />";
    echo "please go back and fix these errors. <br /><br />";
    die();
}


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['Name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Phone_Number']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Chairpersons_Name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Chairpersons_Email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Number_of_Trustees']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Number_of_students'])) {
        died ('we are sorry, but these appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.'); 
        }

$Name = $_POST['Name']; //required
$Email = $_POST['Email']; //required
$Phone_Number = $_POST['Phone_Number']; //required
$Chairpersons_Name = $_POST['Chairpersons_Name']; //required
$Chairpersons_Email = $_POST['Chairpersons_Email']; //required
$Number_of_Trustees = $_POST['Number_of_Trustees']; //required
$Number_of_students = $_POST['Number_of_students']; //required

$error_message ="";
$Name_exp = "^[a-z .'-]=$";
if(!eregi($Name_exp,$Name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}


$Email_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+/.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
if(!eregi($Email_exp,$Email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}


$Phonenumber_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+/.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
if(!eregi($Phonenumber_exp,$Phone_Number)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Phone Number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}


$ChairpersonsName_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+/.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
if(!eregi($ChairpersonsName_exp,$Chairpersons_Name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Chairpersons name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}


$ChairpersonsEmail_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+/.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
if(!eregi($ChairpersonsEmail_exp,$Chairpersons_Email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Chairpersons Email you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}


$Numberoftrustees_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+/.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
if(!eregi($Numberoftrustees_exp,$Number_of_Trustees)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Number of trustees you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}



$Numberofstudents_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+/.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
if(!eregi($Numberofstudents_exp,$Number_of_students)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Number of students you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}

$email_message = "Form details below./n/n";

function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc;","to;","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .="Name: ".clean_string ($Name)."/n";
$email_message .="Email: ".clean_string ($Email)."/n";
$email_message .="Phone_Number: ".clean_string ($Phone_Number)."/n";
$email_message .="Chairpersons_Name: ".clean_string ($Chairpersons_Name)."/n";
$email_message .="Chairpersons_Email: ".clean_string ($Chairpersons_Email)."/n";
$email_message .="Number_of_Trustees: ".clean_string ($Number_of_Trustees)."/n";
$email_message .="Number_of_students: ".clean_string ($Number_of_students)."/n";

//create email headers
$Headers = 'from: '.$email_from."/r/n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."/r/n".
'X-mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail ($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>
```

The Form i want to post

```
<form action="mailscript.php" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Name of School</td>
<td width="204"><input type="text" width="200" Name="Name" value="name of school"/>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" Name="Email" />&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone Number</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" Name="Phone_Number" />&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td width="0">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Chairpersons Name</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" Name="Chairpersons_Name" />&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Chair persons Email</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" Name="Chairpersons_Email" />&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Number of Trustees on your board</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" Name="Number_of_Trustees" />&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Number of Students</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" Name="Number_of_students" />&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br /><br />

<TABLE width="71">
<TR>
<TD><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  /></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</form>
```

Comment: @nathan http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php eregi is a php function (This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix all your regular expression classes. If you want to allow a literal `-` in a class, it must be the first character after the `[`. Otherwise, it's treated as the separator in a character range. For instance,

```
$Name_exp = "^[a-z .'-]=$";
```

should be:

```
$Name_exp = "^[-a-z .']=$";
```

Also, this regular expression only allows a 2-character name, and the second one has to be `=`. I suspect that was a typo for `+`, so it should be:

```
$Name_exp = "^[-a-z .']+$";
```

There are similar problems in all your other regexps, I'm not going to go through all of them and fix them for you.